# How do the changes to Rimmer happen in Timeslides?

Tags: red-dwarf

At the end of *Timeslides*, we see that the changes Rimmer make to the past mean:

> He becomes human again

Obviously this is just a gag, because seconds later:

> he blows up, becoming dead again

and in the next episode he's back to normal.

Despite this being an obvious joke, discrepancies like this are sometimes still discussed or explained (see the opening crawl for Season 3 episode 1).

So it still stands how could his changes in the past have made that happen?

Comment: Butterfly Effect!  Chaos Theory!  ;)

Comment: @davidw I'm sure there must be a reason though, I haven't got access to any behind the scenes commentary or the guide book unfortunately.

Comment: I'm sure there is no reason. It's just a joke. Red Dwarf isn't hard sci-fi, there isn't a detailed logical reasoning for everything, especially time travel stuff.

Comment: In the book, he only missed out on being in the stasis chamber by one minute (because he stopped to comb his hair). Literally anything could have prevented that.

Comment: @Valorum that sounds like the start of an answer

Comment: @Valorum if i recall correctly, he stopped to try parting his hair on the other side. Decided he didn't like it and changed it back again.

Comment: If I recall the episode correctly, Holly the computer even flat out states "dont ask me how but somehow you're alive". Despite having an IQ of 6000 she's not the sharpest tool in the box and can't track the details. Also I'd say the comedy of the joke depends in part on not having an explainable answer.

Comment: Timeslides is full of more holes than most episodes of RD. How everything technically works is a little loose. It also has bugged me because a hologram can't "become" human or "come back to life"; a hologram is a simulated projection of an alive-person, not a ghost. So there probably is no reasonable explanation other than the rule of funny.

Comment: @Jontia any idea where you saw this? It would be the start of a great answer

Comment: @Josh - I don't think it's the hologramme coming back to life so much as the changes mean Rimmer didn't die in the first place (yet still remained on Red Dwarf 3 million years later). But I think you're right that "Rule of Funny" is the reason.

Comment: Right @colmde .. but the Rimmer in that scene "remembers" being a hologram, which doesn't make sense even if history changed. HoloRimmer and AliveRimmer are different consciousnesses unless you think Holograms are Ghosts.  So you can't think very hard about this.

Comment: @josh there is some scope for time travellers to remember their alternate selves I think though?